Expected value of ln(x) when x follows an generalized inversed Gaussian distribution?
I am working on calculating the expected value of $E(\ln(x))$, where $x$ follows an generalized inverse Gaussian distribution with parameters w, $\eta$  and $\lambda$ . The probability density function (PDF) of the generalized Inverse Gaussian distribution is given by:
$$f(x; w, \eta, \lambda) = \frac{\eta^{-\lambda}}{2 K_v(w)}x^{\lambda-1} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}w(\eta x^{-1}+\eta^{-1}x)\right),$$
where ${K_v}$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the second kind. In B. Jrgensen, Statistical Properties of the Generalized Inverse Gaussian Distribution. New York, NY, USA: Springer-Verlag, 1982., the author gave the solution of $E(\ln(x))$:
$$E(\ln(x))=\ln(\eta)+\frac{\partial \ln(K_v(w))}{\partial v},$$
but I don't know how to calculate $\frac{\partial \ln(K_v(w))}{\partial v}$.
Is there another solution of $E(\ln(x))$, and how can we calculate $\frac{\partial \ln(K_v(w))}{\partial v}$?
Thanks a lot for helping me.

@qianqian07 Next time don't forget to also edit the title :)
